# Python: Amazon AWS interface?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

Googling reveals several Python interfaces to [Amazon Web Services (AWS)](http://aws.amazon.com/). Which are the most popular, feature-complete, etc?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I suggest [boto](http://code.google.com/p/boto/) - It's an active project, and boto's new home is now on [GitHub](https://github.com/boto/boto), so you can fork it and add/patch it as desired (not that you need to - it seems very stable).

<strike>The author recently got a job that lets him hack on this part time for work, see [And Now For Something Completely Different...](http://www.elastician.com/2010/07/and-now-for-something-completely.html)</strike>

**Update**: Meanwhile the author, Mitch Garnaat, has fortunately joined the AWS team as well, see [Big News Regarding Python, boto, and AWS](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2012/01/big-news-regarding-python-boto-and-aws.html), promoting this de facto AWS SDK for Python to a semi official one:

> Building on this model, [Mitch Garnaat](http://www.elastician.com/) has also joined the team. Mitch
>   has been a member of the AWS community for over 6 years and has made
>   over 2,000 posts to the [AWS Developer Forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/index.jspa). He is also the author of
>   [boto](http://code.google.com/p/boto/), the most popular third-party library for accessing AWS, and of
>   the [Python and AWS Cookbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/144930544X).

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [pyaws](http://pyaws.sourceforge.net/).  It's not bug-free[*], but seems to work sufficiently well for me. I haven't tried looking for alternatives.

[*] The only bug I've seen was that iterating over the results for a particular query gave me an unexpected IndexError; for some reason the iterator thought it had 11 results instead of the 8 ones it actually had.  I don't really know if the bug is in pyaws or if Amazon manager to return an invalid result for that query.